# Is it necessary to use Static nested class to create a node for linked list

Tags: java, data-structures

Can you please describe the use of below code and how it works.

```
class LinkedList
{
    Node head;  // head of list
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d)  { data = d;  next=null; } // Constructor
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

        llist.head  = new Node(1);
        Node second = new Node(2);
        Node third  = new Node(3);

        llist.head.next = second; // Link first node with the second node
        second.next = third; // Link second node with the third node
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html :

> In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.

It needs to be static in this case because you are creating new `Node`s from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is definitely a good idea, it is not necessary.

You can use a top-level class for a node of your linked list instead of a nested one.

You could also use a non-static class, but you would have to provide a *factory method* on your `LinkedList` class to create new nodes. The result would be a little wasteful, too, because each node would implicitly reference the list.

Note that the reason your code compiles is that your `main` is in the `LinkedList` class. Hence, it can create new nodes without qualifying `Node` with the name of its outer class. If you were to move `main` to some other class, you would have to use this syntax:

```
LinkedList.Node second = new LinkedList.Node(2);
```

Comment: But can you let me know why the Node head has been defined outside of the nested class.

Comment: @PiyushMishra Because it is a member of the outer class, not a member of a nested class.